# Why can't I import this data to my RSACryptoServiceProvider? (C#.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, rsa

For testing purposes, I have a set modulus and private exponent that I want to export into RSACryptoServiceProvider. Here is my code:

```
        byte[] N =
        {
            0x00, 0x8C, 0x35, 0x04, 0xC8, 0x40, 0xB3, 0x67, 0xD8, 0x42, 0x35, 0x78, 0xF6, 0x2A, 0x02, 0xBE,
            0xF7, 0x1C, 0xCD, 0x9D, 0x98, 0x55, 0x16, 0x3F, 0x81, 0xA4, 0xE5, 0x3E, 0x3D, 0x38, 0x27, 0xEE,
            0x0D, 0x8B, 0xAF, 0xB0, 0xBB, 0xBA, 0xA4, 0xE1, 0xF2, 0xB6, 0x79, 0x92, 0x5B, 0x72, 0xBA, 0xC8,
            0xD7, 0x63, 0xA9, 0x60, 0x17, 0xB1, 0x34, 0xF1, 0xA9, 0xE3, 0x46, 0x67, 0xB8, 0x06, 0x9A, 0xCD,
            0x59, 0x95, 0x10, 0x32, 0x74, 0x15, 0x73, 0xB1, 0x09, 0x43, 0x56, 0xA3, 0x0B, 0xE5, 0x6D, 0x2F,
            0x29, 0xF2, 0xB6, 0x6F, 0x5D, 0xA9, 0x55, 0x19, 0x6A, 0x2E, 0xB0, 0x30, 0x6A, 0x3F, 0xAB, 0x9F,
            0x4F, 0xCE, 0x12, 0x66, 0x28, 0xDE, 0xEB, 0x4C, 0x07, 0x9E, 0x5F, 0x24, 0x47, 0x50, 0x39, 0xB8,
            0x8F, 0x0F, 0xB8, 0x8C, 0x62, 0x8C, 0xC7, 0xA8, 0x30, 0x8C, 0xB3, 0x27, 0xA3, 0x13, 0xBC, 0xB0,
            0xA5
        };

        byte[] D =
        {
            0x0D, 0x55, 0xA9, 0x8B, 0xC6, 0x23, 0x89, 0xF7, 0xD6, 0x6C, 0x31, 0x81, 0xF0, 0x02, 0xEC, 0xD8,
            0xA1, 0xC3, 0xA8, 0x7E, 0x69, 0x71, 0x41, 0x3E, 0xFA, 0x48, 0xD7, 0x3F, 0x89, 0x4C, 0xBA, 0xE6,
            0x4C, 0xE7, 0xBB, 0xBE, 0x4F, 0x05, 0x09, 0x7C, 0x45, 0x00, 0x90, 0xFB, 0xE3, 0x90, 0x82, 0x33,
            0x82, 0x06, 0x04, 0xDE, 0x9B, 0xFA, 0xF6, 0x14, 0xFB, 0x49, 0xA1, 0xE9, 0xAD, 0xAF, 0x21, 0x62,
            0x84, 0x45, 0x3F, 0xB4, 0x6C, 0x8A, 0xFF, 0xE1, 0x8C, 0x5B, 0xC9, 0xBA, 0xD5, 0xB3, 0x48, 0x57,
            0x5A, 0xA8, 0x3F, 0x11, 0x28, 0xD3, 0xB3, 0x2F, 0xAF, 0x32, 0x29, 0xC3, 0xA4, 0x20, 0xC4, 0x03,
            0x89, 0xD4, 0x42, 0x0D, 0xAB, 0x5F, 0x06, 0x7F, 0x57, 0xBE, 0xD1, 0x90, 0x0E, 0x5E, 0x47, 0xE8,
            0xC8, 0xFF, 0xF3, 0x0F, 0xC2, 0xD1, 0x58, 0x9A, 0xEC, 0x66, 0x0B, 0x46, 0x9B, 0x79, 0x33, 0xC1
        };

        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        RSAParameters param = new RSAParameters();
        param.D = D;
        param.Modulus = N;
        rsa.ImportParameters(param);
```

Unfortunately, I get the "Bad Data." error when importing parameters (last line). (Note: I really hate this error. I'm going through a several days test process to find the cause because it's not descriptive - at all. It gets thrown whenever a cryptography exception occurs).

Is there anything illegal in this operation?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you have to import the Exponent, or it won't work. Added this line:

```
param.Exponent = new byte[] { 0x01, 0x00, 0x01 };
```